# How can I get rid of these 'console.log is not defined' errors in IE?

Tags: javascript

...without removing the calls to `console.log` obviously. It doesn't need to log or do anything, I just want it to not show an error. I'm trying

```
if (!window.console) {

    window.console = {

        log: function() {},

        error: function() {},

        warn: function() {}

    }

}
```

But that doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: Why doesn't this code work for you? What error are you getting, assuming it runs before anything else?

Comment: @Kobi: That error. `console.log` is not defined. Oh... shoot... I think you might be right actually..haha. The logs get stuffed at the very top of the HTML because they're generated by PHP. Bummer :\

Answer (score 1):

Use debug.log with the following js file instead. It kicks ass.

http://benalman.com/projects/javascript-debug-console-log/

Comment: OP doesn't want to change the console.log statements already sprinkled throughout the code.

Comment: The other answers are direct solutions to the question, but you get a cleaner solution + stored log files that're retrievable with firebug lite and other perks from using debug.log.

Comment: I agree but you are not answering the question, you're giving a better alternative.

Comment: @Abdullah how do you know that? A quick search/replace would do the trick, and I think it's more likely he doesn't want to have to remove them and then put them back in repeatedly throughout a long dev cycle.

Comment: There should be a way to properly have `console.log` ignored.

Comment: Hypothetical situation, what if he doesn't have access to the original JS code but has the ability to inject new code?

Answer (score 1):

Just taking a wild guess, but

```
if (typeof window.console !== "undefined") { ... }
```

would probably solve your issue.

Comment: OP doesn't want to change the console.log statements already sprinkled throughout the code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using

```
function trace(s) {
    try { 
        console.log(s); 
    } catch (e) { 
        //alert(s); 
    }
};
```

`trace(foo);`

Uncomment the alert if you want to get it in IE.

(I got it from another thread here in SO but i don't remember what was)

Answer (score 1):

`window.console = window.console || {log: function() {}};`